# How do I solve the final puzzle of Taurog's Will?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

I am finding the third puzzle of the Taurog's Will puzzle back, named *RAAAAGE!*, quite difficult. I'm having a hard time figuring out which of Taurog's gear to take first, and when I should actually use GETINDARE and then convert it.

[image]

How can I solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start with the shield, which makes you take no damage against the three level 1 opponents.  Defeat all of them.
2. Grab GETINDARE and then get Taurog's Blade.  You can now level up by killing the Level 2 Dragon Spawn, but before you do so, you'll want to hit the Level 3 Meat Man twice to whittle him down.
3. Finish off the Level 3 Meat Man.  Then hit the Animated Armour once to take off a level of death protection and reduce his damage.
4. Hit the Level 3 Dragon Spawn, then use GETINDARE to finish him off and level up.
5. Pick up Taurog's Helm.
6. Hit the Warlock and use GETINDARE to finish him off.  Then fight the remaining monsters (other than the level 9s).
7. Pick up Taurog's Armor.
8. Destroy GETINDARE to give yourself enough piety to get Unstoppable Fury.
9. Defeat the boss!